# I am getting double quotes error in sqlite

Tags: sql, excel, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am preparing my SQL query in excel after that c/p to sqlite editor. I tried two different editor and the problem is same. For example in Excel this is how my query looks

[image]

[image]

```
INSERT INTO jokes_table (id, title, joke, cat, fav, bookmark)
VALUES ("9", "There''s this dyslexic guy... he walked into a bra...", "There''s this dyslexic guy... he walked into a bra...", "Bar", "0", "0");
```

in sqlite editor it becomes

```
"INSERT INTO jokes_table (id, title, joke, cat, fav, bookmark) VALUES (""1"", ""What do you call a cow with no legs?

Ground Beef!"", ""What do you call a cow with no legs?

Ground Beef!"", ""Animal"", ""0"", ""0"");"
```

There is extra quotes starting and end of query. I know that's happens because of "bottom line" but if I remove the extra quotes manually the editor can run code without any error even if it have bottom line. There is 10.000 query and i can't remove manually. How can I fix it? Thanks a lot

Comment: Isn't it possible to replace 2 double quotes with 1 double quote everywhere. Or use single quotes in Excel rather than double quotes.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. It's not about using double or single quotes. Everyting fine in excel, after I copied queries when i past to sql editor it's adding extra quotes itself. You can see on screenshoots in red circles.

Comment: When all is in your SQLite Editor (with double double-quotes surrounding values) you should be able to find and replace all at once - don't you ?

Comment: When you select the content of all relevant excel cells and paste them in SQLite Editor, do you get 2 double-quote issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the best way but you can save it as `Formatted Text (Space delimited)` and use that to copy paste later on.

In Excel 2019

1. Save As > More Option >
2. In `Save As Type` dropdown choose `Formatted Text (Space delimited)`
3. Rename your file to filename.**txt** (.txt & not. prn)

Open and copy paste from there

See below screenshot for format

[image]

---

One more workaround is to use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v7.8.6/).

1. Open csv in notepad++
2. Press Alt and select all `"` in the beginning of your queries & delete.
3. Select `;"` -> Press `CTRL+H` -> Replace `;"` with `;`.
4. Done

See GIF below

[image]